# Smooth animate wpf window width and height together with left and top property

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, wpf-animation

I can not animate height and width of window **together** with top and left property.
*(If you want to run this, link to download example is at the end of this question.)*

Always when I run this animation, my window firstly **smooth move to new location** (change smoothly top and left) and also **smoothly animate width** property during window move.. **but window height not responds**.. **then window height jumps from one value** (old height) **to the new** height.

My WPF application is easy - only for testing this (4 properties, 1 button and 1 function):

Firstly I added this properties to my window (file: `MainWindow.xaml.cs`):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Position to lock for change size in horizontal way (x)
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LocationLockHorizontalProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LocationLockHorizontal", typeof(AlignmentX), typeof(Window));
    /// <summary>
    /// Position to lock for change size in vertical way (y)
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LocationLockVerticalProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LocationLockVertical", typeof(AlignmentY), typeof(Window));
    /// <summary>
    /// Location to lock for change size.
    /// </summary>
    public AlignmentX LocationLockHorizontal
    {
        get { return (AlignmentX)GetValue(LocationLockHorizontalProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LocationLockHorizontalProperty, value); }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Location to lock for change size.
    /// </summary>
    public AlignmentY LocationLockVertical
    {
        get { return (AlignmentY)GetValue(LocationLockVerticalProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LocationLockVerticalProperty, value); }
    }
```

Then I added to the same file one new procedure for create and start animation:

```
public void AnimateResize(double changeWidth = 0d, double changeHeight = 0d, double durationMilisec = 200.0)
{
    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();

    DoubleAnimation daw;
    DoubleAnimation dah;

    // animate window width
    if (changeWidth != 0.0)
    {
        daw = new DoubleAnimation();
        daw.From = this.ActualWidth;
        daw.To = this.ActualWidth + changeWidth;
        daw.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(durationMilisec));
        daw.AccelerationRatio = 0.4;
        daw.DecelerationRatio = 0.6;
        // this.BeginAnimation(Window.WidthProperty, daw);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(daw, this);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(daw, new PropertyPath(Window.WidthProperty));
        sb.Children.Add(daw);
    }

    // animate window height
    if (changeHeight != 0.0)
    {
        dah = new DoubleAnimation();
        dah.From = this.ActualHeight;
        dah.To = this.ActualHeight + changeHeight;
        dah.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(durationMilisec));
        dah.AccelerationRatio = 0.4;
        dah.DecelerationRatio = 0.6;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(dah, this);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(dah, new PropertyPath(Window.HeightProperty));
        sb.Children.Add(dah); // this.BeginAnimation(Window.HeightProperty, dah);
    }

    DoubleAnimation dax;
    DoubleAnimation day;

    // animate window move in horizontal way
    if (LocationLockHorizontal == AlignmentX.Center || LocationLockHorizontal == AlignmentX.Right)
    {
        dax = new DoubleAnimation();
        dax.From = this.Left;
        switch (LocationLockHorizontal)
        {
            case AlignmentX.Center:
                dax.To = this.Left - changeWidth / 2.0;
                break;
            case AlignmentX.Right:
                dax.To = this.Left - changeWidth;
                break;
        }
        dax.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(durationMilisec));
        dax.AccelerationRatio = 0.4; dax.DecelerationRatio = 0.6;

        Storyboard.SetTarget(dax, this);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(dax, new PropertyPath(Window.LeftProperty));
        sb.Children.Add(dax); // this.BeginAnimation(Window.LeftProperty, dax);
    }

    // animate window move vertical 
    if (LocationLockVertical == AlignmentY.Center || LocationLockVertical == AlignmentY.Bottom)
    {
        day = new DoubleAnimation();
        day.From = this.Top;

        switch (LocationLockVertical)
        {
            case AlignmentY.Center:
                day.To = this.Top - changeHeight / 2.0;
                break;
            case AlignmentY.Bottom:
                day.To = this.Top - changeHeight;
                break;
        }
        day.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(durationMilisec));
        day.AccelerationRatio = 0.4; day.DecelerationRatio = 0.6;

        Storyboard.SetTarget(day, this);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(day, new PropertyPath(Window.TopProperty));
        sb.Children.Add(day); // this.BeginAnimation(Window.TopProperty, day);
    }
    sb.Begin();
}
```

In `MyWindow` initialization in the same file `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, properties are set to this values (to fix animation to bottom point vertically and center horizontally):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LocationLockHorizontal = AlignmentX.Center; // fix center point when animate resizing
    LocationLockVertical = AlignmentY.Bottom; // lock bottom corner of application
}
```

My application has 1 button and for it I set click event for random call of previous procedure:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.AnimateResize(new Random().NextDouble() * 400.0 - 200.0, new Random().NextDouble() * 500.0 - 250.0, 1000.0);
}
```

For complete example here is my xaml `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="Test_HeightAndTopAnimation.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="300" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
  <Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

I read several articles ([Wpf - Animate height from bottom up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535222/wpf-animate-height-from-bottom-up) - I don`t have a grid, or [WPF: Animation is not smooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559485/wpf-animation-is-not-smooth)) but nothing looks related to this problem.

**Link to zip file with example**: [Application code on Google Drive](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6B1wtU16petdDlVQkhXbGxDajFfU3hRbnpIRzkydWJRLVFJ/edit?usp=docslist_api)

*Only last note: I use Windows7 64bit and .NET 4.5*

Comment: Yeah, this is a weird one. If you add the `Height` animation into the `Storyboard.Children` collection first, then the `Height` animates smoothly and the `Width` animation stutters.

Comment: It seems the problem is in Window class. You can't animate its Width and Height properties simultaneously. Here is a [workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332385/animating-a-wpf-window-width-and-height).